# How to raise customtkinter frame in my program

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

Okay I am a newbie to GUI programming and I have checked like 15 different resources on tkinter how to work with frames but I still do not understand the logic at all so please help.
I am trying to write a program and basically I want to open a different frame for each button I click and then do some more operations which I will figure out once I get the basic interface to work.

I have split my code into multiple py files so that I can split the workload as well.
For the structure of the classes I have followed the customtkinter tutorial description and adjusted it to what I want my program to do, but I do not understand how to implement the button command the right way

**My main.py:**

```
import customtkinter
from MainFrame import MainFrame


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Alcohol Documentation")
        self.geometry("1000x650")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.main_frame = MainFrame(self)
        self.main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="nsew")

        self.product_frame = ProductFrame(self)

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

**The selection menu frame:**

```
import customtkinter
from ProductFrame import ProductFrame

def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

class MainFrame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1),  weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1), weight=1)

        self.order_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="New Order", width=350, height=100, font=('montserrat', 20))
        self.order_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20,10), sticky="es")

        self.event_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="New Event", width=350, height=100, font=('montserrat', 20))
        self.event_button.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10, sticky="ne")

        self.product_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="New Product", command=lambda:raise_frame(ProductFrame), width=350, height=100, font=('montserrat', 20))
        self.product_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=(20,10), sticky="sw")

        self.data_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Data Management", width=350, height=100, font=('montserrat', 20))
        self.data_button.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=10, sticky="nw")
```

**The frame I want to raise when clicking the "New Product" Button (defined in MainFrame):**

```
import customtkinter

class ProductFrame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1),  weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1), weight=1)

        self.label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Hello")
        self.label.grid()
```

Comment: There are several questions on switching frame in StackOverflow. Do some research.